# get nearest places first when search in google autocomplete places drop down in angular 2

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-location-services

I am using google autocomplete locations in angular 2 project and it is filling with locations in a drop down.
I have a new requirement.If user is in a place called ABD , when doing search in the drop down it must shows ABD first not ABC,which means the nearest places to the user must comes in the drop down first.

The autocomplete location code i had written is given below

```
autoCompleteLocation() {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {

        let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {

        });

        autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                //get the place result
                let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

                //verify result
                if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
                    return;
                }

                //set latitude, longitude and zoom
                this.LocInsertObj.PreLocation = place.formatted_address; //place.name;
                this.LocInsertObj.PreLocation = this.LocInsertObj.PreLocation.indexOf(place.name) < 0 ? place.name + ", " + this.LocInsertObj.PreLocation : this.LocInsertObj.PreLocation;
                this.LocInsertObj.PreLocationLat = place.geometry.location.lat();
                this.LocInsertObj.PreLocationLong = place.geometry.location.lng();
                this.LocInsertObj.zip = 123;


                this.isCurrentLocationSet = true;
                $(".userProfile-container").trigger("click");
                $("#location").focus();


            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: is this done ??